# How to set opacity in QtableWidget cell when setting cell background color

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to insert few rows in a QtableWidget and setting the cell background color as follows:

```
        int rowcount = tableWidget->rowCount();
        tableWidget->insertRow(rowcount);
        QTableWidgetItem *coloItem = new QTableWidgetItem("");

        tableWidget->setItem(rowcount, 0, coloItem);
        coloItem->setBackground(Qt::GlobalColor(i)); //Qt::GlobalColor(fColor)
```

Now I want to set opacity of the cell , how can i do it.
I couldnot find anything related to QtableWidget.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how a cell with opacity should look like. Do you have another widget behind QTableWidget and want some cells to be semi-transparent? Can you post a picture?

Comment: Hi Pavel, Unfortunately i dont have privilege to post pictures, but background widget is Qwidget. on the same widget i have QgraphicsView and QGraphicsScene where I am displaying some colors and setting the opacity, now i want to show the same colors with same opacity in the QtableWidget

Comment: So, you don't need semi-transparency, you just need to display specific color, am I correct? In that case calculating that color and setting it as cell background would be enough. (You can always post a *link* to a picture.)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_oYS4i7-wQMWWpzdzBEcFdpNkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Pavel- the first pane shows a QgraphicsScene with rectangles filled with color but opacity is set for all the rectangles , now same colors are been displayed in the QTableWidget but i can't set opacity , so the colors looks different in Qtablewidget.

Comment: Why do you set opacity in QGraphicsScene if you don't need semi-transparency? You could tune lightness in HSL representation of the color if you just need lighter colors.